# Google login gives error

Tags: codenameone

I tried to implement google login in my project but it is giving me unknown host error after signing in with gmail username and password & then pressing the allow button. I have also kept android.playService.plus in build hint. Are other build hints necessary too? I didn't find proper documentation or blog to apply it as well.My code is as follow:

```
if (googleLogin.isNativeLoginSupported()) {
    if (!googleLogin.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        googleLogin.doLogin();
    }
    AccessToken at = googleLogin.getAccessToken();
    System.out.println("token " + at.getToken()); // this value is null
} else {
    if (!googleLogin.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        googleLogin.doLogin();
        System.out.println("not logged in : not native login");
    }
}
googleLogin.setCallback(new LoginCallback() {
    @Override
    public void loginFailed(String errorMessage) {
        Dialog.show("Login Faild", "Retry Login", "Retry", null);
        google_signIn(res);
    }

    @Override
    public void loginSuccessful() {
        System.out.println("successfull");
        new NewForm(res).show();
    }
});
```

Error:

```
Received exception: Unknown host
java.lang.Throwable: Unknown host
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.describeError(WebEngine.java:1402)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1341)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1100(WebEngine.java:1219)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1206)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2387)
at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2231)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFail(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFail(URLLoader.java:843)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFail$93(URLLoader.java:826)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader$$Lambda$197/728465605.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$63/2017575979.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$62/1811810557.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$54/5182121.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you clarify if the login itself works despite this?
Have you tried on device? This might be a failure of the simulator code as that is more fragile by its nature

Comment: The error I found out, youtube.com was not opening in my laptop. I change the redirect url to facebook.com and it worked. In simulator it is redirected to a webpage(facebook.com). How can I open new form instead of the redirect webpage? I don't know if the login succeed or not. It doesn't show login fail dialog or 'successful' log in output frm setCallback method. In device, situation is worse. It keep on showing choose account and when an account is selected, this 'choose account dialog box' is shown again & again. I didn't get any error while debugging  But AccessToken is null.

Answer (score 0):

On the simulator we need to use web login as there is no native login and it uses a web page which might not look great.

On the device native login is used and should feel seamless. It's important to check devices for this sort of functionality as they behave very differently.

Comment: Hello shai, on simulator, it redirects to the redirect url and stays in that web url where as in android devices, the choose account dialog box with a no of gmail ids is shown but after choosing one, it again shows the same dialog box. What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: If it's Android 6+ it's possible that this is related to an issue that was fixed the other day. We'll have a fix for it out next week on Friday

Comment: This was fixed.

Comment: It now works in simulator but in devices it shows choose account dialog box again and again and LoginCallback listener is still not called.

Comment: Are we talking about Google Login? As far as I know Steve just tested this on Android 6+ device